# Unable to open an application using CYpress

Tags: automation, cypress

Using Cypress I am trying to automate an application URL. on hitting the URL, a window alert opens but is not readable for to enter user id and password.
I was advised by few to pass the username and password in the URL of the application, now i can by the alert, but nothing appears in the application page its showing blank.
Please advise if any other ways are there

Comment: Could you share some code so we can understand better?

Comment: so basically i am giving a hypothetically situation. I have an application say https://www.rahulshetty.com. Imagine to use this application u need to input your userid and password. Now when i hit the application in a browser an alert pops up. This alert i am not sure how to read using cypress. one of thesuggestion was to embed userid and pwd within the URL. Doing so i could get the URL opened , but the application body was not visible. Any advise on this would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution

cy.visit("url",{
headers:{
Authorization:"Value"
}
})

To obtain the Authorization value, using postman hit the url after giving the UID and PWD and take from Headers, the value.